# vim autocomplete search from middle of word

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Are there any plugins that provide **middle of word** auto complete in **Edit** mode?

Currently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will only work if you type the start of the word.

I would like to type:

```
if (cool
```

and get matches like:

```
**cool**Function  
very**cool**  
tiny**cool**aid_variable
```

ignoring case would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I have several custom completion plugins. Have a look at:

- [BidiComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4658): Insert mode completion that considers text before AND AFTER the cursor.
- [InnerFragmentComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4804): Insert mode completion based on fragments inside words.